# Wanted to install Ubuntu in dual boot, formatted the boot partion

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot

I wanted to install Ubuntu in dual boot mode with Windows. During the installation, I selected the option to format the EFI partition, and expected to use GRUB to boot into both Linux and Windows. Unfortunately, GRUB only boots into Linux. Is there a way to fix it? `os-prober` returns empty:

```shellsession
root@V:~# os-prober 
root@V:~#
```

The output from fdisk:

```shellsession
# fdisk /dev/nvme0n1 -l
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 953.87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk model: Micron_2450_MTFDKBA1T0TFK               
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: B1E78D43-BFB6-4A7E-905A-C32FACCCA85A

Device              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1       2048     206847     204800   100M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2     206848     239615      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3     239616 1553252115 1553012500 740.5G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 1553252352 1758050303  204797952  97.7G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p5 1758050304 2000406527  242356224 115.6G Linux filesystem
```

Comment: Now you know why you NEVER format the ESP to do what you intended. The way to fix it is by booting Windows installation media and following instructions to repair boot; then change the boot order in UEFI back to Ubuntu and finally boot Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub`. Needless to say, this ISN'T an Unix or Linux question, it's all about Windows.